# ending gnuplot process using PyGnuplot

Tags: python, gnuplot

I am using gnuplot (through Python with PyGnuplot) as a live plotter for numeric data from an Arduino. Additionally I want to save the plot at discretionary points. Whenever I try saving a pdf/jpg, from gnuplot while live-plotting, gnuplot lodges.

I think it is necessary to restart the gnuplot-process before saving a plot as pdf - what simply won't work using PyGnuplot.c('quit') or similar commands. When I use different python scripts for live-plotting and saving a pdf, all works fine, but I know that it cannot be necessary to have two scripts running.

Here is a running (respectively not running) minimal example:

```
import random,time
import PyGnuplot as gp
filename = "data.txt"

def rand():
    return random.random()

def writetxt(file,info):
    fobj = open(file, "a")
    fobj.write(info)
    fobj.close()

def liveplot(file):
    gp.c('plot "' + file + '" with lines')

def plotinfile(dat):
    gp.c('set terminal pdf')
    gp.c('set output "example.pdf"')
    gp.c('plot "' + dat + '" with lines')
    gp.c('unset output')
    gp.c('set terminal x11')

for i in range(10): 
         onerow = str(i) + " " + str(rand()) + " " + str(rand()) #simulate incoming data
         print(onerow) #print in console for comparison
         writetxt(filename ,onerow + "\n") #write data into txt-file
         liveplot(filename) #liveplot the data from txt-file
         if i == 4: #simulate an arbitrary point for saving
            plotinfile(filename) #save graph from txt-file to pdf
         time.sleep(1)   #incoming data occurs only every second
```

Comment: Are you plotting, saving, and then repotting? `pg.c("plot 'example.out' u 1:3 w l t 'y=(x-25)*sin(x-25)'")
pg.pdf('example.pdf') 
pg.c("replot 'example.out' u 1:(-$2) w l t 'y=25-x'")`

Comment: I thought the 'replot' command is only to spare the before used plotting parameters and elsewise the same as 'plot'. Using it instead of 'plot' didn't change anything.
Using pg.pdf('exa.pdf') instead of pg.c('set terminal pdf') + pg.c('set output "exa.pdf"') + pg.c('plot [...]') also didn't change anything.

Comment: I've spoken with the maintainer of the project and he's looking for a multi-platform solution: https://github.com/benschneider/PyGnuplot/issues/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to add curves to your plot or add data points, and save intermittently. If so, something like this should suffice:

```
python
>>> import PyGnuplot as gp
>>> gp.c('plot sin(x)')
>>> gp.pdf('sin_graph.pdf')   # discretionary save point 1 
>>> gp.c('replot cos(x)')     # add a new curve  
>>> gp.pdf('sin_and_cos_graph.pdf') # discretionary save point 2
```

If you only have the pdfcario terminal not pdf, then you'll need to work around the pygnuplot c.pdf script by writing the pdf yourself:

```
>>>filename = 'sin_graph.pdf'
>>>gp.c('set term pdf enhanced size 14cm, 9cm color solid')
>>>gp.c('set out "' + filename + '";')
>>>gp.c('replot;')
>>>term='x11`  # or whatever term you typically use
>>>gp.c('set term ' + str(term) + '; replot')
```

You could wrap this routine into a function with `filename` and `terminal` as arguments. Regardless, you'll have to do this series of commands every time you wish to print your pdf.

Comment: this is not working. it only shows me the first curve and both pdf's are not readable

Comment: This works for me. What OS are you on? Also, check if you have the 'pdf' terminal in gnuplot.

Comment: Win 8.1 Pro :( 
pdfcairo is available instead gnuplot moans about something else: 
>>> gp.c('plot sin(x)')
>>> gp.pdf('singraph.pdf')
>>> gnuplot> set term pdf enhanced size 14cm, 9cm color solid fsize 12 fname 'Helvetica';
line 0: unrecognized terminal option
gnuplot> set term x11; replot
         line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list
 ...Is the above example also running for you?

Comment: pdfcairo doesn't support "fsize, and fname" settings.  There is a workaround; I'll edit my response.

Comment: @FranzJosef I've spoken with the maintainer of this project, and he's looking for a multiplaform solution to this issue: https://github.com/benschneider/PyGnuplot/issues/11

Comment: Thanks great work. Now I know, that it's simply impossible to end gnuplot using PyGnuplot. Maybe in the future. Without your help and the help from the others I still would be searching...

Answer (score 0):

gnuplot will not close the output file until either (1) the terminal type is changed to something else or (2) there is an explicit command "unset output".  Otherwise gnuplot waits to see if there is another plot command that will go into that same output file.

Comment: Thanks - that was clear and this change made the pdf readable, but gnuplot anyway lodges. Though changing terminal-type or unset output gnuplot saves the new incoming data instead of plotting it (while live-plotting is lodged).

Comment: I may not understand what you are asking.  New data is only consumed in response to a plot command  ("plot" "splot" "replot").  Changing the terminal will complete the previous plot but will not create a new one.  The next plot will be created by the next plot/splot/replot command.

Comment: Yes - of course it gets a new 'plot' command. With every incoming data a new plot is generated (live-plotting), but whenever it should plot into a file it lodges afterwards (stopping the live-plot).

Comment: "gnuplot saves the new incoming data instead of plotting it" this is solved, but it still lodges, whenever I try to plot after saving a pdf. 
By the way this is happening leastwise at two of my computers (windows)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was: the used terminal was not at hand. Using another terminal fixed the issue. Thanks for your help. In PyGnuplot the terminal x11 is used - which is not available for me (I still don't know why, don't know how to install it and still don't know how to end the gnuplot process using PyGnuplot...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing (Gnuplot not closing properly sometimes) has been addressed with the recent update to PyGnuplot, version 0.12.3. This new version provides a feature that allows you to create multiple figure instances and close them separately, which should correctly end the Gnuplot process.

Moreover, it also supports using Gnuplot's exceptional fitting algorithms, which could be beneficial for your use case.

The use of PyGnuplot has changed slightly, though. Now, you import a 'gp' class from PyGnuplot to create new figures. Here's an example of how to do this:

```py
from PyGnuplot import gp
fig1 = gp()
fig1.a('plot sin(x)')

fig1.quit()  # This will terminate the gnuplot instance associated with this figure
```

With the above code, you can create multiple Gnuplot instances and terminate them as needed. This should help solve the issue you're facing when trying to save a plot as a PDF while live-plotting.

Also, with the new update, data is passed directly to Gnuplot rather than saving it to a 'tmp.dat' file. If you want to revert to the previous behavior (which runs faster on my linux system with a ram disk), you can do so with the following code:

```py
gp.save(data, filename='tmp.dat')
gp.c('plot "tmp.dat"')
```

This should address your current problem by enabling separate handling of live-plotting and saving the plots. You no longer need to run two separate scripts for these tasks.

For the source of this info, see [the Gnuplot 0.12.3 release notes](https://github.com/benschneider/PyGnuplot/releases/tag/0.12.3).

Comment: @starball, good point! [Gnuplot 0.12.3 release notes](https://github.com/benschneider/PyGnuplot/releases/tag/0.12.3)